# Is there any such thing as "polar regression"?

Tags: regression, circular-statistics

I don't know of where this would come up in a practical sense, but I had this crazy idea this morning that maybe if given various pairs $(r, \theta)$ in polar coordinates that one could attempt to fit a curve through them, using $\theta$ as the response variable and $r$ as the explanatory variable.

For simplicity, we could start with a "linear regression" of sorts through a set of points $\{(r_i, \theta_i)\}$.

I suppose one could naively assume a model of the form 
$$r_i\cos(\theta_i) = \beta_0+\beta_1 r_i\sin(\theta_i) + \epsilon_i$$
(recalling that $x_i = r_i \sin(\theta_i)$ and $y_i = r_i \cos(\theta_i)$ in rectangular coordinates), but this ruins the point of making $\theta_i$ the "response" variable of $r_i$, given that functions of $\theta_i$ appear on both sides of the equation.

**Has there been any literature developed on any sort of regression in polar coordinates?**

Of course, since various values of $\theta$ are coterminal, the domain of $\theta$ will probably need to be truncated. What may also complicate things slightly is that $r > 0$.

Comment: I believe this is what [directional statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics) is about, but I've never spent much time reading about it, so I couldn't say much more than that.

Comment: If the original data comes as (x,y) pairs, why not just convert it to polar and then regress r = a + b * theta (or whatever relevant functional form for your application)? I seem to be getting sensible results in a simple test I did, though I'm a little worried that I'm not really taking into account the non-linearity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an enormous amount of statistics related to this under the name [circular or directional statistics](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directional_statistics).

Your case is not so well described though.

What is the 'switch' that you were thinking of by introducing polar coordinates?

Do you mean to solve a situation of a non-negative variable, e.g. some count, as function of a cyclical variable, e.g. hour of the day, by picturing it as a curve and solve it with the mechanisms for curve fitting in euclidean coordinates?

Comment: I would have to think about your question some more. But at least I know what to search if I wanted to explore the literature. Thanks. (+1)

Comment: There is also an R package named 'circular' containing lots of tools for analysis. In comparison to your case more interesting problems arise when the *dependent* variable is circular. You got the problem that regular techniques like solving least squares by matrix equations, do not work (imagine the residual distance between 23:59 and 00:01).